# Image segmentation in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-segmentation

I have the image [image: shape image]

I am looking for python solution to break the shape in this image into smaller parts according to the contour in the image.

I have looked into solution on Canny and findContours in OpenCV but none of them works for me.

### Edit:

Code used:

## using Canny method

```
import cv2 import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('area_of_blob_maxcontrast_white.jpg') edges = cv2.Canny(img, 100, 200)
cv2.imwrite('area_of_blob_maxcontrast_white_edges.jpg',edges)
```

## using findContours method

```
import numpy as np 
import argparse 
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('area_of_blob_maxcontrast_white.png')

lower = np.array([0, 0, 0]) upper = np.array([15, 15, 15]) shapeMask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)

(_,cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(shapeMask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                            cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) print "I found %d black shapes" % (len(cnts)) cv2.imshow("Mask", shapeMask)

for c in cnts:
    # draw the contour and show it
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow("Image", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Please share a sample code of your attempts so people can find and point out where your code needs to be changed.

Comment: Where is the image.?

Comment: this is the link to the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVBTT.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick is to make your faint single pixel boundary slightly bolder. I do it by changing any white pixel that has two adjacent black pixels (above, below, to the left or to the right) to black. (I do it extremely slow, though. I'm pretty sure there must be a smarter way to do it with OpenCV or Numpy.)

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

import numpy as np
import cv2

THRESH = 240

orig = cv2.imread("map.png")
img = cv2.cvtColor(orig, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Make the faint 1-pixel boundary bolder
rows, cols = img.shape
new_img = np.full_like(img, 255)    # pure white image
for y in range(rows):
    if not (y % 10):
        print ('Row = %d (%.2f%%)' % (y, 100.*y/rows))
    for x in range(cols):
        score  = 1 if y > 0 and img.item(y-1, x) < THRESH else 0
        score += 1 if x > 0 and img.item(y, x-1) < THRESH else 0
        score += 1 if y < rows-1 and img.item(y+1, x) < THRESH else 0
        score += 1 if x < cols-1 and img.item(y, x+1) < THRESH else 0
        if img.item(y, x) < THRESH or score >= 2:
            new_img[y, x] = 0       # black pixels show boundary

cv2.imwrite('thresh.png', new_img)

# Find all contours on the map
_th, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(new_img,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
print "Number of contours detected = %d" % len(contours)

# Fill second level regions on the map
coln = 0
colors = [
    [127, 0, 255],
    [255, 0, 127],
    [255, 127, 0],
    [127, 255, 0],
    [0, 127, 255],
    [0, 255, 127],
]
hierarchy = hierarchy[0]
for i in range(len(contours)):
    area = cv2.contourArea(contours[i])
    if hierarchy[i][3] == 1:
        print (i, area)
        coln = (coln + 1) % len(colors)
        cv2.drawContours(orig, contours, i, colors[coln], -1)

cv2.imwrite("colored_map.png", orig)
```

Input image:

[image: Faint outline of regions]

Output image:

[image: Map with four colored regions]

Here I color only the direct descendants of the outmost contour (`hierarchy[i][3] == 1`). But you can change it to exclude the lakes.

Comment: Thanks Andriy, that's what I am looking for.

Comment: @Esther, I'm glad it helped. Please, consider choosing my answer as "Best answer".

Comment: sorry, i am new to using this. May I know how should i do that to choose your answer as Best answer

Comment: @Esther, "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green". See [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png).

Comment: NOTE: faster way to make the border bolder would be to apply a custom kernel `[[0,1,0],[1,0,1],[0,1,0]]` with `cv2.filter2D` function to compute the `score` as a matrix.

Comment: to follow up with the question I ask, I have another query.

Comment: @AndriyMakukha i get this error  if you can help me  _th, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(new_img,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

Comment: @A.khalifa, remove `_th,` in that line.

Comment: @AndriyMakukha, now i get this error Invalid number of channels in input image:  'VScn::contains(scn)' 'scn' is 1, help plz

Comment: @A.khalifa, I don't know this error. But it might be because you use RGBA or grayscale image instead of RGB image.