# Detect and crop card in image with multiple objects using width and height or color of card

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have a card with multiple objects in one image and I want to crop the card using width and height or color of the card.

I can crop using code below:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('/Users/akram/Downloads/img.jpg', 1)
x = 0
y = 0
width = 500
height = 500
cropped_img = img[y:y+height, x:x+width]
cv2.imshow("cropped_images", cropped_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

But when I have other image width card `width = 500 and height = 500` and   `x = 200 y = 100`

I need to edit my code with `x = 200 and y = 100`.

The problem is that I don't know the position of the card in all time, so I need to create a dynamic code to crop the card with any position x or y in image.

I don't know how can I achieve this purpose, I'm new in OpenCV and computer vision in fact I'm new in this domain.

Example image

[image]

Anyone can help me to resolve this issue and thanks ?

Comment: Can you post an example image or two?

Comment: @AndriyMakukha i add image usually image can be have two objects card and signature, thanks for help !!

Comment: you can detect the card as a contour and then get the bounding box around it and then crop the bounding box.I hope this link will help you:https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/da/d0c/tutorial_bounding_rects_circles.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Elyas Karimi pointed out, you can detect the card by finding contours. One way to do it is to find the biggest bounding box for the input image and then crop according to that bounding box. For the sample image, you'd get the ID card this way.

Here is a sample implementation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread('Image.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # convert to grayscale
# threshold to get just the signature (INVERTED)
retval, thresh_gray = cv2.threshold(gray, thresh=245, maxval=255, \
                                   type=cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv2.imwrite('Image_gray.jpg', thresh_gray)  # debugging

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh_gray,cv2.RETR_LIST, \
                                   cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Find object with the biggest bounding box
mx = (0,0,0,0)      # biggest bounding box so far
mx_area = 0
for cont in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cont)
    area = w*h
    if area > mx_area:
        mx = x,y,w,h
        mx_area = area
x,y,w,h = mx

# Crop and save
roi=img[y:y+h,x:x+w]
cv2.imwrite('Image_crop.jpg', roi)

# Draw bounding box rectangle (debugging)
cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(200,0,0),2)
cv2.imwrite('Image_cont.jpg', img)
```

You could also find the biggest bounding box under the detected card to get the signature as well (or use hierarchy for this purpose).

Input image:

[image: original image with ID card and signature]

Bounding box:

[image: image with bounding box drawn around the ID card]

Crop:

[image: cropped image - ID card (resized 50%)]

Comment: if i have two card with same width and height, how can i get two card with name of each card, for example id_card.jpg and bank_card.jpg and signature.png ?? if you want i post new question no problem, thank you very very match !!

Comment: @A.khalifa, you can read my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51189261/5407270) to see how to find all top level contours. (Note that `hierarchy[i][3] == 1` needs to be changed to `hierarchy[i][3] == -1` with the latest version of cv2).

Comment: Thanks @AndriyMakukha

Comment: Hi @AndriyMakukha Can you please share Java code. Your above solution looks nice.

Comment: @FalduJaldeep, no, I don't have Java code.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the card as a contour and then get the bounding box around it and then crop the bounding box.

I hope this link will help you: https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/da/d0c/tutorial_bounding_rects_circles.html

Answer (score 0):

First find the contours of the threshold image then find the max area indicate that area using rectangle. Crop the area and save it.

```
import cv2

img=cv2.imread("1.jpg")
img=cv2.resize(img,(1080,800))  #resize
imgGrey = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, threshold = cv2.threshold(imgGrey, 245, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV) #thresholding
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
if contours:
    contours = max(contours, key=lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x)) #max contours finding using area
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contours)
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),[0,0,255],1)
    crop_img=img[y+1:y+h,x+1:x+w]  #crop the area
    cv2.imwrite("Crop_Image.jpg",crop_img) # save crop img
cv2.imshow("selected area",img)
cv2.imshow("croped area",crop_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output:
[image]